# How to use AWSDateTime in Java

Tags: java, android, aws-amplify

Trying to figure out how to input a AWSDateTime. I don't want to use Java 8.

createDate requires Temporal.DateTime

```
com.amplifyframework.core.model.temporal
public static final class Temporal.DateTime

private final @ModelField(targetType="AWSDateTime", isRequired = true) Temporal.DateTime createDate;
```

Is there any other way I can accomplish this?

```
Date input = new Date();
LocalDate date = input.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(); --> this requires Java 8

Todo todo = Todo .builder()
        .createDate(date)
        .build();

Amplify.DataStore.save(todo,
        result -> Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Created successfully"),
        error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp",  "Error creating", error)
```

Comment: I don’t want to use Java 8 either. There are significant improvements in later versions. Is it the same for you? Java 8 is 7 years old, and Java 16 is out. java.time still counts as the modern Java date and time API, and is worth using. It was improved already in Java 9.

Comment: If I use Java 8 in Android I have to increase the API number, and I don't want to exclude devices just because of Java 8. You can do fine with not using java 8.

Comment: Or [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the function in DateUtils.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html

AWSDateTime

An extended ISO 8601 date and time string in the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ.

```
String date1 = com.amazonaws.util.DateUtils.formatISO8601Date(new Date());

Todo todo = Todo .builder()
        .createDate(new Temporal.DateTime(date1))
        .build();
```

Note: This will store the date in GMT time.

Comment: Though I'm using kotlin this works fine! However, must replace `new Date` with `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

`Temporal.DateTime` has a public constructor that takes a `java.util.Date` and offset in seconds:

```
public DateTime(@NonNull java.util.Date date, int offsetInSeconds)
```

You can use it like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
int offsetMillis = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(date.getTime());
int offsetSeconds = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(offsetMillis);
Temporal.DateTime temporalDateTime = new Temporal.DateTime(date, offsetSeconds);
Todo todo = Todo.builder()
    .createDate(temporalDateTime)
    .build();
```